# Who is coming after the Mountain?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), the Hound tells his brother, The Mountain:

> You know who's coming for you

What is he referring to?

Comment: Himself, by any chance?

Comment: Many theorise that the Hound saw the Mountain dying in the fire as a kid, and he expressed this much, so the Mountain pressed his face against it, and this line in the episode is a reference to that.

Comment: Hype is coming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What is he referring to?

### Himself.

He's telling the Mountain that they always knew it would come down to just them finding out who's best and Sandor [the Hound] getting revenge for the things Gregor did to him...

It goes back to their childhood when the Mountain gave the Hound his scars...

> Gregor [the Mountain] nearly burned off half of Sandor's face because he found Sandor playing with a toy that Gregor had discarded.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Sandor_Clegane)</sup>

Comment: Hashtag CleganeBowl.

Comment: [#GetHype](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-5HvlzVZpk)

Comment: @Möoz, I wish that was an answer that could be upvoted multiple times to the highest echelons of all Stack Exchange sites.  It is simply that awesome!

Answer (score 2):

We don't really know, but there are other possibilities besides the Hound himself.

The Hound recently had an experience with fire where he sees a vision. This seems to be a unique ability, as evidenced by the look of surprise in the faces of the Beric and Thoros. Much of his life was shaped by the Mountain pressing his face into fire. The connection here could mean many things. Perhaps the Hound has seen something in the fire that informs him of what the Mountain experienced with the fire. He may even be referring to the Lord of Light. Seeing something in the fire would explain how the Mountain has "always known."

The Hound could also be referring to Beric Dondarrion. Beric was tasked by Ned Stark with killing the Mountain, but instead was impaled by the same. This was the first time Thoros brought Beric back to life. This was relatively recent, however, so the words "always known" don't necessarily make sense here.